# Can I use worksheet_change for a specific column only?

Tags: excel, vba

Here is what I have. I am using a drop down list of 3 values in order to hide columns. Each value has specific columns that are unique to it and when a value is selected, I need the other columns that are not associated with it to be hidden.

I have used the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Select Case Target.Value
    Case "Marine"
        Columns("T:X").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Columns("Z").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

    Case "Inland"
        Columns("S").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Columns("U").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

    Case Else
        Columns("T:X").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Columns("Z").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Columns("S").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Columns("U").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End Select
 End Sub
```

This works when I select the values from the drop down but as soon as I click on another cell in the worksheet then the hidden columns reappear. I want to be able to select a value in the drop down and for the cells to remain hidden until I select another value in the drop down. Can anyone help me with this? I have tried to use `WorkSheet_SelectionChange` but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this (you'll need to adjust it) at the beginning of your code, to check the range that was clicked and eventually abort the sub when user clicks outside your special range.

```
Dim isect As Range
Set isect = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("$a$8:$a$48"))
If isect Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
```

You could also check the address:

```
If Target.Range Like "$X$*" Then...
```

---

**Update:**
On the other hand, if the columns must be shown/hidden depending on where you click in column A, for example, then I would rather use the SelectionChange event. Here is a sample:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
        Dim isect As Range
        Set isect = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("$a$8:$a$48"))
        If Not isect Is Nothing Then
            select case Target.Value
                .....
            end select
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @iDevlop thanks for the reply. The drop down works but when I click on any other cell then the hidden columns are shown. I would like the columns to remain hidden even when I click on other cells.

Comment: Hey @iDevlop, could you please assist me with this issue? Your previous answer is very close to what I want to do.

Comment: I can try...go ahead. Not sure I will be able to answer instantly, since I must also work a bit :-) and be interrupted by other things, but go

Comment: Thanks @iDevlop...when I select a value in a drop down, it correctly hides the selected columns. However, when I select another value in a cell below the previous one, I want to be able to go back to the previous selected cell and have actions done to be the same, i.e. if I had column D and E hidden for "Marine" and I select "Inland" to hide column F and G, then if I select "Marine" again then those columns should be hidden again. Is this possible?

Comment: Not clear. Where are the values "Marine", "Inland" or other stored ? Is it stored ONCE in the sheet or is that once per line ?

Comment: There is a drop down with three values "Marine", "Inland" and "Estuarine" and this are found in a column. When each is selected, then different columns are hidden if they aren't associated with the value selected. I want this to happen to the entire column so that if I change one value say for "Marine", I can be able to come back to it and click on the cell and the hidden columns associated with "Marine" will be still be hidden. Is that clearer?

Comment: "found in a column" does that mean there is a RANGE of cells with "Data Validation/List" ? Then see my Update above.

Comment: Hi @iDevlop, I used your previous solution but changed the event to `Worsksheet_SelectionChange` and it works! The only thing is that I need to sometimes click away and click back on the cell for it to register that it has been selected and columns hidden. Can I edit your post with my solution?

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the code with Target.Address.

For example, the Drop down is in the Cell "B2" then,
the code would be as follows:

```
If Target.Address(True, True) = "$B$2" Then
    Select Case Target.Value
    Case "Marine"
        Columns("T:X").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Columns("Z").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

    Case "Inland"
        Columns("S").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Columns("U").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

    Case Else
        Columns("T:X").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Columns("Z").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Columns("S").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Columns("U").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End Select
End If
```

Additionally, guessing the purpose of your code, I have tweaked it further.
The simplified version would look like:

```
If Target.Address(True, True) = "$B$2" Then
    Select Case Target.Value
    Case "Marine"
        Columns("S:Z").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Columns("T:X").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Columns("Z").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Case "Inland"
        Columns("S:Z").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Columns("S").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Columns("U").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

    Case Else
        Columns("S:Z").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End Select
End If
```

Comment: Hi @Aditya Deo, thanks for the reply. The drop down is on the entire column. How will I be able to use a range in this case?

Comment: Also, after the columns are hidden, I want to also change the values in other drop downs. And these values should remain even when I go and change the drop down in column. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is your `Case Else` statement. The worksheet change event will be triggered when you go to other cells, and because the value is neither "Marine" nor "Inland," this `Else` statement gets executed and all the columns are set to `Hidden = False`.

Since you have 3 options in the drop-down, you only need to make the third `Case` statement explicit instead of a catch-all.

Comment: Hi @Jay. I used the `Case Else` to ensure that if there is no cell chosen then all are not hidden. How can I ensure that when no selection is made that all the cells appear? I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Select Case Target.Column

Case 2

    If Target.Value = "Marine" Then

        Columns("S").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Columns("U").EntireColumn.Hidden = False            
        Columns("T:X").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Columns("Z").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

    ElseIf Target.Value = "Inland" Then

        Columns("S").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Columns("U").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Columns("T:X").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Columns("Z").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Else

        Columns("T:X").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Columns("Z").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Columns("S").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Columns("U").EntireColumn.Hidden = False

    End If

End Select

End Sub
```

Now in line 4 of the code where the case is selected, give the column number of the column number in which you have the drop-downs or validations enabled in the sheet, in the given case it's 2, which represents column 'B', and Boom!

I have made a little correction based on my past experiences in your code. Assuming that for the Marine entries have to be made in column 'S' and column 'U' and the Island entries are to be made in columns 'T:X' and 'Z'.

In your original code, if you have selected "Marine" first in a particular line item, and later corrected it to "Island", then you'll only end up having all the required columns hidden, but you would have wanted the Island columns un-hidden (to probably enter data in those fields) which I have corrected now.

Comment: Hi MMS, thank you for the reply, but I get an error since my Select Case does not have an End Select. And it doesn't want me to add it anywhere after the code!

Comment: @PeterKhayundi The code works fine for me! Exactly paste the entire code in the worksheet in which you have the data.