# How can I UPDATE a date based on a cell change in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

This is a little background. In Army Aviation we have to conduct a Night Goggle (NG) flight at least once every 60 days. This date is gathered from the last time an NG flight is conducted in order to display and track currency with the mode.

[image: An image to help with my question]

With the picture linked above as reference (screenshot of actual book), I'm trying to UPDATE the date on another tab (Display Panel) with the DATE (B COLUMN) (B28) based on the INPUT (> or = 1.0) placed in the CELL (P COLUMN) (P28).

And with that, any time another NG hour entry is made below in the same column, it'll perform the script again, provided the aforementioned applies.

I've tried banging out a few VBA lines, but I'm not having any luck.

Comment: There is the Worksheet_Change Event which you can set to a specific column as target with Target.Column = column as number. Which column should respond to an input? Column P? Some examples https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236804/can-i-use-worksheet-change-for-a-specific-column-only      http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2010/10/13/excel-vba-macro-runs-when-worksheet-changed/  Sounds like you might combine this with Target.Value >=1.0

Comment: Showing the columns and row numbers helps when posting images of your data so we are clear on the positioning of elements though we can work it out from your labelling of B28. What is the name of the current sheet and where in Display Panel are you putting the updated date?

Comment: The current page the script and "reference picture" would be/is located on is called "Flight Log," while the date which should be displayed and updated is located in C32 on "Display Panel"

Comment: Note that self-answers are most welcome here. Next time you have your own solution, please add it below in the answer section. I have done so for you as "community wiki" - if you would like to replace this with your own answer, please re-post it under your own name, and I'll delete the CW copy.

Comment: This question may close in its present state, since you've mentioned you, erm, "banged out some VBA" but did not include that code. The question may be more useful to future readers if you can retrospectively add that when you next sign in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the shell of what I think you need which goes in the code pane associated with the sheet which you are monitoring column P of...

It fires if there is a change in column P and if the value is >=1

There is 1 further bit of logic. I am only updating C32 if the new value is greater than the existing.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim updateCell As Range
Dim lastDateCell As Range
Set updateCell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Display Panel").Range("C32")
Set lastDateCell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Display Panel").Range("AA32")

If Target.Column = 16 And Target.Value >= 1 Then

       If Target.Offset(, -14) > updateCell Then 

           lastDateCell  = updateCell 
           updateCell = Target.Offset(, -14) 'only update if greater than existing

       End If

End Sub
```

Code in code pane of `Flight Log` sheet:

[image: Flight log code window with code]

Comment: I'll plug this in and give it a try! Thank you for the reply!

To answer you question, the date would and SHOULD only change if the value is 1.0 or greater.

So I'd say yes, it'd have to be the latest, or rather, most recent date that had a NG value of 1.0 or greater.

Thanks!

Comment: it will only if greater than 1 but if someone goes and alters any earier P column value and it is >=1 then the date will be set to that.

Comment: Hmm... understood. Is there a way to tell it not to accept any change unless it's associated with the most current date in COLUMN B? Thank you for responding and helping me with this!

Comment: that's ok. In order to keep track of the latest date you could have a check that only adds the new date if greater than the existing in C32. i have added this in. Let me know if the formatting of the date needs to be changed or if displays as expected.

Comment: Thank you so much, you've been a huge help! I'm not great with this stuff, but I've been trying to "part and piece" the outcomes I want based on this community and their prior posts/questions. It's amazing how much you can learn be using YouTube, Udemy, and Google haha!

Comment: very true. If you are willing to learn then SO really helps. I like the Wise Owl VBA tutorials and Contextures Posts as well as ExcelIsFun stuff on YouTube.

Comment: It works! After testing it a few different ways, the only way it "doesn't" work is if say I entered a value and it computed correctly, but realized I "miscalculated" the 1.0 I put in, if I correct it to a 0.8, it still keeps the date associated with the miscalculated hour I put in.

Comment: Yes because it wouldn’t fire again. You could have a prompt that asks the user to confirm the value they are entering; you could manually change the date in c32 but the logic becomes a lot more involved if you want to keep track of what the prior value was and revert dates if you later change a p column value to <1.

Comment: Manually resetting might be the easiest way. You could always have a hidden cell which kept track of the prior date such that whenever you replaced the current c32 you place the existing one somewhere else. You’d be ok unless you made two incorrect entries.

Comment: i've added a line that puts the last date before you changed it, into cell AA32 of same sheet as C32. This hopefully is out of sight. You can change this if required.

Comment: You're awesome, and I thoroughly appreciate your time! I've "clicked" the vote up button, but apparently, seeing as I'm a "noob" to the group, it won't change the Publicly displayed score because I have less than 15 reputation.. =/

Comment: That said, you have done well with this question being upvoted!

Comment: Thanks! And I found it, so you've definitely earned it!

Comment: Ta. Let me know if any further niggles.

Comment: I was able to fix it, but it was missing the last "End If" thanks!

Comment: An If statement that is all on one line doesn't have an End If. An If statement across multiple lines must have an End If. Did you split the inner If across more than one line?

Comment: It was most likely me! I posted the script above in my comment, and with it, modifications within, and outside of the script I use.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted the solution on behalf of the question author)*.

Below is what I added.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Sheets("Flight Log").Unprotect "Password Here" 'This unprotects the sheet to allow changes

Dim updateCell As Range
Dim lastDateCell As Range
Set updateCell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Computations").Range("A36") 'This is the primary date location
Set lastDateCell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Computations").Range("A40") 'This is the backup date location

If Target.Column = 16 And Target.Value >= 1 Then 'This check P column for the value

       If Target.Offset(, -14) > updateCell Then 'If "P" returns the value, date in "B" is grabbed

           lastDateCell = updateCell 'This updates the primary date cell
           updateCell = Target.Offset(, -14) 'This ensures date is not overridden by lesser value

       End If

End If
Sheets("Flight Log").Protect "Password Here" 'This line reprotects the sheet
End Sub
```

Additionally, I use two LOOKUP functions to evaluate the HOUR(s) in reference to the dates grabbed by the VBS:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(A36,'Flight Log'!B:B,'Flight Log'!P:P),"/// NG DATE ERROR ///")
```

and,

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(A40,'Flight Log'!B:B,'Flight Log'!P:P),"/// NO B/U DATE ///")
```

after this, I use another IF function to verify the HOUR wasn't miss-entered

```
=IF(A37>=1,A36,IF(A41>=1,A40,"NG HOUR ERROR"))
```

The simple IF functions check and verify the HOUR wasn't entered incorrectly by the Pilot--which would prompt the VBS script to grab that DATE--and then re-entered to it's intended "correct" value. For instance, "Pilot enters time into block, pilots realizes time he entered was wrong, and corrects it." This will keep his error, from being an overall error.